# Popup close issue in Yii framework

Tags: yii

How to close popup Dialog Box in "Submit" action ? Now popup gets closed but it renders to empty page,

[image]

My View Code,

```
<?php
echo CHtml::form('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
    echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'name');
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('submit' => 'SaveAttachDocuments'));
    echo CHtml::endForm();?>
```

My Controller Code,

```
public function actionSaveAttachDocuments()
        {
            $model=new DocumentAttachmentModel();

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            $filename =CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'name');
            echo "model -> ".$filename;
            $model->type =pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $model->name =pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $model->save();

             echo CHtml::script("window.parent.$('#Attach-New-Documents').dialog('close');      window.parent.$.fn.yiiGridView.update('Attach-new-grid');");
                        Yii::app()->end();


        }
```

Comment: what do you mean it renders to empty page ? better if you can add to question what happens after you close. may be a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: i dont want to go to any page, just "New Attachment" popup should close and the grid should be updated...

Comment: remove this line from the code, Yii::app()->end(); should work now.

Comment: still it goes to saveAttachDocuments url (new page) only...popup not closing

Comment: Check the answer i posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code line,

```
Yii::app()->end();
```

and then include the view file to render. (in your case it should be the view that contains the form and grid as per your image)

```
$this->render("admin");
```

so if i put things together you code should look like,

```
public function actionSaveAttachDocuments()
        {
            $model=new DocumentAttachmentModel();

            // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
            $filename =CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'name');
            echo "model -> ".$filename;
            $model->type =pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $model->name =pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $model->save();

             echo CHtml::script("window.parent.$('#Attach-New-Documents').dialog('close');      window.parent.$.fn.yiiGridView.update('Attach-new-grid');");
           $this->render("admin"); // your view file


    }
```